# Island hopper: how many different ways to cross the ravine

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve the following math question:

AB needs to cross a ravine safely, using floating islands to help. She is able to make small leaps from 1 floating island to the next. Or, with a large leap, she can miss 1 floating island altogether. If there are `n` (where `n` is an integer) number of floating islands, how many different ways are there of crossing the ravine?

Would anyone please suggest me any formula to find the answer?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint. Work out the counts by hand for small values of $n$ and look for a pattern. You should encounter a familiar sequence of integers.

Comment: I would take $a_n$ as the number of ways to cross the ravine when $n$ floating islands are in front of you. Note $a_0=1,a_1=2$. Can you develop a recurrence relation for $a_n$ when $n\geq 2$ by considering the size of your first step?

Comment: The question is stated a little imprecisely. It sounds like the islands are supposed to be all in a row and you always only leap forwards? If you allow backwards leaps things get more complicated.

Comment: Indeed, what if the islands are arranged in some sort of two-dimensional array, and you can make all kinds of leaps sideways or in other directions? Clarification needed!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, yes, all islands are in a row and only forward leaps allowed.

Comment: @Ethan, I tried that way. For 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 floating islands, I got 2, 3, 5, 7, 12, 13 different ways respectively. I am not sure if it is correct because I cannout figure out the pattern. Can you please help?

Comment: @Matthew, sorry, I could not develop a recurrence relation.

Comment: @Gerry, islands are all in a row. Not arranged like 2D array. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You were close, there are eight ways for 4, and then thirteen ways to cross for n=5. Maybe if you go back and look at your work you might be able to spot the ones you missed. I also missed some when I tried counting them out.

Comment: When I read the problem, it seemed to me to say (" she can miss 1 floating island altogether") that only one "large leap" would be allowed.  The present form of the Question lacks context and is ambiguous, not incorporating the clarifications that were given in Comments by the original poster.  It may be that this was an assigned exercise intended to elicit the *recurrence relation* solution, though this is inconsistent with how I read the problem, so it needs editing by the original poster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is one floating island, we can either jump over that or land on it, so there are two ways. If there are two floating islands, we can either jump over the first one, or the second one, or land on both, so the number of ways to cross is 3.

Let's make a recursion relation. Let's say the number of ways to cross $n$ floating islands is $F(n)$. If we add another island at the beginning, the total number of ways to cross the $n+1$ islands is $F(n)$ for all the crossings where we don't jump the new first one, plus $F(n-1)$ for all the crossings where we jump the first one. So $$F(n+1)=F(n)+F(n-1),$$
and we already have $F(1)=2$ and $F(2)=3$, so $F(n+1)$ is just the usual Fibonacci number for $n$.

You can easily confirm this by writing out the first few crossings. Here is a graphic demonstration.

[image]